# Python:Sharing codes of models between 2 modules

Tags: python, model

I'm climbing my learning curve in Python and try to understand where to put everything.

I originally have a python module in a folder and then a sub folder src, in this src folder I will then have my main source files say main.py then I will have models folder storing my models codes.

```
/myproject/src/main.py
/myproject/src/models/a-model.py
/myproject/src/models/b-model.py
```

So my main will import the model like this:

```
from models.a-model import a
```

Then when I package the zip file I just zip the myproject folder with that folder structure and deploy and everything is fine.

Now I have another new module doing something different but need to use the same models.

I can easily duplicate them all and code separately and deploy. But I would like to share the codes to the models, so that when one model changes, I only need to update once, instead of 2 places.

My new module is like

```
/mynew/src/main-b.py
/mynew/src/models/a-model.py
/mynew/src/models/b-model.py
```

What is the best practise to do this?

Do I put like this?

```
/myproject/src/main.py
/mynew/src/main-b.py
/models/a-model.py
/models/b-model.py
```

And then update the import?

But I have doubt how do I deploy? Do I also have to setup the same folder structures?

Comment: Add the path of the directory containing the `models` package to your `PYTHONPATH` variable of the environment where you run the code of either project. Then the `from models import ...` will find them.

Comment: @StevenYong are you using Pydev as your IDE?

Comment: No @direprobs, why?

Comment: @StevenYong I was thinking you're creating source folders with Pydev. But now it's clear you're not using Pydev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would be adding `/myproject/src/models` to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Python adds the directories listed in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to `sys.path`, the list of directories where Python searches when you try to import something. This is *bad*, because modifying `PYTHONPATH` has its own side effects, fortunately, virtual environments provide a way to get around those side effects.

Alternatively and much better you could add your modules to `site-packages` directory, `site-packages` is added to sys.path`by default, this obviates the need to modify`PYTHONPATH`. To locate the`site-packages` directory, refer to this page from Python Documentation: [Installing Python Modules (Legacy version)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/install/#how-installation-works).

You could also use [LiClipse IDE](http://www.liclipse.com/) which comes with [Pydev](http://www.pydev.org/) already installed. [Create source a folder from the IDE](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html) and link your previous project with your newer project. When you link your projects the IDE adds the source folders of your older project to the `PYTHONPATH` of your newer project and thus Python will be able to locate your modules.